# Run more than four DB2 Container within a CentOS7 VM leads to resource errors

Tags: docker, db2, centos7

this is my first question in stackoverflow.com. I hope the huge text is not too confusing :)

We have an issue with our DB2 Express database run as dynamic container instance which have an effect to all DB2 containers running on same time. I’ll try to describe the infrastructure in detail as well as I can.

We are using Jenkins as CI server which contains several pipelines to build, test and deploy our development. As result the pipeline starts up some different containers  (e.g. Apache, JBOSS, DB2) to start automatic GUI tests of the application we are implementing. Two kind of pipelines running during the development process: One to check the own branches (we call it feature driven tests), one to check the finally merge into development (we call it develop test). In case of the feature driven tests the pipeline was implemented to start up the containers, run the check of high prior test and shutdown all dependent containers finally. The develop test pipeline is doing almost the same as the feature driven test but starts with shutting down of all running containers of the previous job,  start new containers and let them still running after the job finishing.

Each DB2 container even created by a job starts with an empty database, filled up per SQL Scripts (create the database objects, insert initial data into tables,…). During the GUI checks the application reads from or writes into the database. We’ve implemented a connection test as health checks.

In this constellation we  want to start a free amount of feature driven tests. Of course we have a physical limit but if we try to run more than 3 feature driven tests all DB2 container got the an unhealthy status. It also affects the DB2 container of the development test what is independent to the feature driven tests.

In our analyze we found out each unhealthy DB2 container throws two kind of error messages:

- su: execute /bin/bash: Resource temporarily unavailable
- {{}}KB-1956: SQL30082N Security processing failed with reason "15" ("Processing Failure")

Both kind of error messages looks like an issue to start processes because of missing resources. Our checks with the command “ulimit” didn’t show any abnormalities neither in the running container nor on host server. We setup the “max user processes” from 4096 to unlimited. The host has got the same setting. We tried to setup the Dockerfile with running the commands during the startup phase. But without any effect.

The status unhealthy occurred not always at the same line of our scripts. In most cases the containers changes the status during the database got filled-up but also the GUI tests are lead to this effect. We tried to reproduced the effect on another machine. These checks run without the pipeline but with using the same SQL scripts. We couldn’t reproduce the effect in this way.

We are using this environment:

OS: CentOS7 (VM): 7.5.1804
DB2 Express database version 11.1 as container (CentOs based)

Do you have any idea about the reason and how we can fix it?

Kind regards, Michael

Comment: Resource limitations?  How many concurrent containers run Db2-express?  How much RAM/CPU-cores do you have?  There may be more details in the db2diag.log , and in the syslog or /var/log/messages etc both in the containers and on the host.

Comment: Are the containers probably mounting/using the same volumes or shares for the DB files?

Comment: Hi mao and Markus. Some more informations for you. The VM gives this Server configuration per lscpu command:

Comment: The VM gives this Server configuration per lscpu command: CPU: 40, THreads per core, all CPUs onilne10 cores per sockets. RAM: 125G(total), 15G used, 15G free, 1,9G shared, 95G buff/cache, 107G available. 
I checked the db2diag.log on the development container but I didn't found any hint to this issue. But this is possible because the container was rebuild in meanwhile. But that is a good idea for deeper investigations.

Comment: Regarding the volumes: Yes, we assumed that point, too. But the containers have seperated IDs which are generated by dynamically. All containers of a job run in there own network. But it really looks like as an usage of same files, whatever. But we didn't how. Because of the running container we assumed that the host processes configuration was the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Because you might not have enough cores or ram to run the machines, I propose using the db2 container operator and running it on Kubernetes rather than docker.

Also looking at your error it is a security error
SQL30082N Security processing failed with Reason Code 15
"Security processing at the server failed"
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/135213

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer, or asking the OP for more information? In case of the former: please [edit] the post to show *how* it solves the problem. In case of the latter, please delete this, as the "post answer" button is for answers only, see [answer]. Questions addressed to the OP should be put into comments.